# Cycle plugin: Can't insert a slide counter on slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, cycle, counter

I'm using [Cycle Slider](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)
with slide conunter. I'm having plroblems to implement a fadein controls on mouse over... they have a slider like that, but with no slide counter... I tryed to implement the counter on the fade control slider and the fade control on the slide conter slider, but no success... Any tips?

Here is the code of a slider with fade controls that I'm trying to use: http://jsfiddle.net/sLCQf/1/
. I cant put the slide counter in that...

Answer (score 1):

Try using the pager option in jQuery cycle.

see
http://jsfiddle.net/nwe44/sLCQf/2/

for a demo of this in action based on your fiddle. Obviously you'll want to style it a bit better than my beautiful border.